# Clickable region of JS+CSS animated button is cut off on Squarespace but not on CodePen

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace, codepen

The + button on [this page of my portfolio site](https://www.charliemoody.com/mograph) provides more context and information on videos. It's composed of a simple "plus"-shaped SVG that I made contained within a circle-shaped div (border-radius: 100%), and animates out an additional div upon click.

[On CodePen](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/MWOpeop), where I originally coded this, the entire button (constituting both divs) is clickable. When I copied the code over to Squarespace, I noticed the upper half of the button is no longer clickable.

Since it works as intented on CodePen, I don't *think* there's an issue with the code (some relevant portions below but all is more easily visible in the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/MWOpeop).

// HTML snippet:

```
    <body>
     <div id="feed">
      <section class="slide" id="bB1">
       <div class="containerBox cBBefore">
        <div class="textContainer">
          <div class="textSubCont">
            <div class="plusButton noSelect">
              <div class="plusSpan inactivePlus"></div>
            </div>
              </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </section>
```

// CSS Snippet:

```
    .plusButton {
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: auto;
     cursor: default;
     box-sizing: content-box;
     border-radius: 100%;
     right: -1.333vmin;
     top: -1.333vmin;
     height: 5vmin;
     width: 5vmin;
     z-index: 6;
     background: rgba(79, 76, 220, 0.75);
     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(
     -0.25vmin 0.5vmin 0.5vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33)) !important;
     filter: drop-shadow(-0.25vmin 0.5vmin 0.5vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33)) !important;
     }

    .plusSpan {
      content: url(https://www.charliemoody.com/s/plus.svg);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform-origin: center;
      -webkit-transform-origin: center;
     }

   .activePlus {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-765deg);
     transform: rotate(-765deg);
     -webkit-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.25, 1);
     transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.25, 1);
     }

   .inactivePlus {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
     transform: rotate(0);
     -webkit-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.25, 1);
     transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.25, 1);
     }
```

// JS snippets

```
   function enableButtons() {
     let allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".plusButton");
     let allButtonSpans = document.querySelectorAll(".plusSpan");
     let allCBs = document.querySelectorAll(".containerBox");

     for (let i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
      allButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function classToggle() {
      allButtonSpans[i].classList.toggle("inactivePlus");
      allButtonSpans[i].classList.toggle("activePlus");
      }
     }

    function pauseOnPlus() {
      let plusButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".plusButton");
      let vids = document.querySelectorAll(".vidElement");
      for (let i = 0; i < plusButtons.length; i++) {
      plusButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
       if (vids[i].paused) vids[i].play();
       else vids[i].pause();
      });
     }
    }
   
    function loadTheRest() {
     enableButtons();
     pauseOnPlus();
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", loadTheRest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!! Easy fix. Just needed to add "box-sizing: content-box;" to .plusSpan in the CSS.